# No Known Class Method for Selector 'valueWithCGPoint'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I imported this PRTween library to my project.

Here are the source codes:

[PRTween.h](https://github.com/domhofmann/PRTween/blob/master/lib/PRTween.h)

[PRTween.m](https://github.com/domhofmann/PRTween/blob/master/lib/PRTween.m)

But it cant compile and gives me a lot of error

I really have no idea why is this happening because I have no experience with Objective C before.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like your just not importing Foundation.... Add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to the header of your file

Comment: you may need `<CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>` too for the CG types

Comment: Your target isn't compiling for OSX, and not iOS, by any chance?

Comment: Yes @trojanfoe I am compiling for iOS

Comment: Are you sure?  Please update your question with the compiler line for this file (you can find it in the build log, top-left, and expanding the line for this file).

Comment: I am very sure, because if I remove the library, my app will launch as usual @trojanfoe

Comment: Please post the compiler line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler warns you that:

> No visible @interface for X

Chances are you're just forgetting to import the header file that contains this class.

In your case, you will want to import both `Foundation.h` and `CoreGraphics.h`:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

**OR**

You might be import looping. Say you have `fileA.h` and `fileB.h`, if `fileA.h` imports `fileB.h` and `fileB.h` imports `fileA.h`, then the compiler will get stuck in an import loop, usually causing it to flag up completely unrelated errors about missing @interfaces.

Have a careful look back through your headers and make sure you're not import looping. If you are, you probably just want to move one of the file imports from the `.h` to the `.m` or completely re-think your dependancy structure.

Comment: Added both to the .m and .h files. Still have the same error

Comment: Okay, you might be import looping then. This is where say you have file A and file B, file A imports file B and file B also imports file A. This will cause a loop and the compiler will flag up random warnings about missing @interfaces. I would have a careful look through your imports and make sure you're not looping. Also, remove the framework imports from the `.m`, they belong only in the `.h`.

Comment: @JayVDiyk did this help you? be sure to accept if it did :)

Comment: @JayVDiyk Do you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

PRTween.h is missing `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`.  After adding that, these errors and warnings went away.